# Deleted .nomedia file but still photos in that folder not visible in gallery

Tags: photos, hidden

Created an .nomedia file in a folder and it worked. But now I've deleted that file but still photos are not visible in gallery app.How to recover from this? Any help?

Comment: Check if .nomedia file is still there in hidden state.

Comment: cehcked many times.its not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After photos are added, they need to be scanned by the [media-scanner](/questions/tagged/media-scanner) before they'll show up in Gallery and other apps. Normally, the app that creates the photo asks the media scanner directly to add the new photo, but in this case, because you've removed the .nomedia yourself, nothing has yet triggered the file to be scanned.

You can find apps to trigger the rescan on Google Play, but be careful if your phone has KitKat or later: Android changed the way media rescanning works, to save battery, so apps written for earlier Android versions simply won't work on KitKat. Alternatively, if the folder in question is on removable storage, simply remove it and then add it again, and Android will re-scan the whole filesystem.

Comment: mine is 4.4.2 .so not working

Answer (score 2):

Simply move the pics to another folder then copy them back. They will appear in the gallery

Answer (score 1):

just rename the folder and change it back again to the original name.
worked for me with whatsapp media folder.